# Отправить в <form> содержание тега <option>

Tags: php, html, post, form, select

Есть форма:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="enter phone number"><br>
    <select name="URL">
    <? echo '<option value="'.$url.'">'.$section_name.'</option>';
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send 2 site" />
 </form>
```

Есть обработчик:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $page = $_POST['URL'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
}
```

Как в обработчик передать значение $section_name? Оно отличается и не может быть равным $url . Значение $url изменить также нельзя по условию.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input name="sectionname" id="sectionname" type="hidden" />
  <select name="URL" onchange="writeSectionName(this)">
    ...
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send 2 site" />
</form>

<script>
  function writeSectionName(select) {
    document.getElementById("sectionname").value = 
      select.options[select.selectedIndex].textContent;
  }
  window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    writeSectionName(document.querySelector("select[name='URL']"));
  });
</script>

...    
$section = $_POST['sectionname'];
```

Comment: Заполняет, но не отправляет:

`array(4) { ["phone"]=> string(12) "+79123456789" ["sectionname"]=> string(0) "" ["URL"]=> string(38) "url" ["submit"]=> string(11) "Send 2 site" }`

Comment: Надо вызвать `writeSectionName` на загрузку страницы.

Comment: Ошибся. Отправляет, но первое значение пустое, ведь подставляется в input только при изменении.

Comment: @theblackpost Уже добавил.